# Optimizing time series generation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series in which any value `valX` at time `tX` has two other values associated with it (`minX` and `maxX`). As you can see in the figure bellow, those values always satisfy `minX < valX < maxX`.

Now, I would like to create a new time series that associates, for each `tX`, the first value in the time series that crossed `minX` or `maxX` at `tY > tX`:

[image]

This is the implementation I have come up with:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

# An example data frame
np.random.seed(1)
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['min', 'max', 'val'])
df['max'] += 1
df['val'] = (df['min'] + df['max']) / 2.

# An auxiliary column, that will be shifted
df['shift'] = df['val'].copy()

# This is the time series I am looking for (initialized with NaN values)
df['result'] = np.nan

# Main loop
LIMIT = len(df)
for i in range(LIMIT):
    df['shift'] = df['shift'].shift(-1)
    df['result'].update(df['shift'][((df['shift'] < df['min']) | \
                                     (df['shift'] > df['max'])) & \
                                    (df['result'].isnull())])

# Data frame is well-formed
df
```

Which shows the correct result:

[image]

I wonder if there is a better (specially faster in execution) way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) often works well for these type of problems. You could also a get a similar result with `cython` with more annotations.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def generate_values(mins, maxs, vals):
    N = len(vals)
    ans = np.empty(N)

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i, N):
            if vals[j] < mins[i] or vals[j] > maxs[i]:
                ans[i] = vals[j]
                break
        else:
            ans[i] = np.nan
    return ans
```

A bit verbose, but very fast.

```
In [278]: %%time
     ...: LIMIT = len(df)
     ...: for i in range(LIMIT):
     ...:     df['shift'] = df['shift'].shift(-1)
     ...:     df['result'].update(df['shift'][((df['shift'] < df['min']) | \
     ...:                                      (df['shift'] > df['max'])) & \
     ...:                                     (df['result'].isnull())])
Wall time: 62 ms


In [281]: %timeit generate_values(df['min'].values, df['max'].values, df['val'].values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: With `numba` a new world of possibilities has been opened-up in front of me. Thank you very much.